# How to format a string of days-of-the-week using Java?

Tags: java

Using Java 6, and with an input string (from an array of such entries) that comprises any combination of the days-of-the-week in the order that follows

MTWThF

how can one format the string such that one gets

M,T,W,Th,F  (i.e. a comma after each day except the last day)

The string represents the working days for an employee.
Once again, here's the 'catch' (no Java pun intended) -- any employee can work any combination of days.

So, the input at times could be

MW

and so the output should be

M,W

I have used the replaceAll() method and I have come close but I've had to call the method several times on the string to do this.
So I thought maybe someone had done this -- or something like it -- before and found an simpler way.
Thank you

Comment: Show us your code. what have you got working so far?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
String work = ...;
String csvwork = work.replaceAll( "(?<=.)([FMTW])", ",$1" )
```

Here, `(?<=.)` is a *zero-width positive lookbehind non-capturing group:* What follows matches after whatever matches the pattern within, i.e., the period in `(?<=`.`)`. This is the pattern matching the `all character class`. Thus, the following pattern is anchored *after any character*. The second part `([FMTW])` is a *capturing group* matching a single character consisting of one of F, M, T or W. Therefore, the entire pattern matches any F, M, T or W after any character. The second argument to `replaceAll` defines the replacement of the F/M/T/W as consisting of a comma and whatever was captured by the (first and only) capturing group.

Comment: Btw, laune, can you explain the regex used here?  It would be of great help to me (and others as well I suspect).  Thank you.

Comment: Explained it. - The javadoc for java.util.regex.Pattern is rather terse, but I'm sure there are other resources on the web.